# Can I work out where the iTunes Media Folder is located?

Tags: windows, itunes

I've written a simple batch file which, after doing some stuff to a video file that arrives periodically, dumps the output into the `Automatically Add to iTunes` folder so that iTunes will add it to its library when it is next started.

At present, the path to this folder is hard-coded into the script.

This isn't very flexible as my iTunes Media folder is `E:\` but I know that others may have it in `C:\Users\username\My Music\iTunes\` or (if they are on XP) `C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Music\iTunes\`.

Is there any way to work out where the iTunes Media Folder is located? I've trawled the registry but cannot find anything which would hint at its path.

Comment: Side note: I could write something to upload it automatically to iTunes, but I've found this to be a bit flaky and it keeps forcing iTunes to pop up when a new video arrives (which is annoying when you're using the computer) hence why I just want to drop the videos into the correct folder.

Comment: could you not do a search for "iTunes Music Library.xml" and grab the directory its in?